# Android SQL database backup file format to cloud

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my Android app I have a SQL database. The user adds some data in app and he is able to backup the db to Google drive.

This works fine, I am doing it like this example:

```
  String Path = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("mydbname.db").getAbsolutePath();
   File filePath = new File( Path);
   driveServiceHelper.createFilePDF(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(...)
```

and in driveServiceHelper.createFilePDF (part of code):

```
            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetaData = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
            fileMetaData.setName("mydbname.db");
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.sqlite3", filePath);
            myFile = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetaData, mediaContent).execute();
```

The problem is, on google drive it is stored as db file, easily read by ani SQl viewer. However I don't want anyone to stole the data from db, because it contains info that I have collected for years of experience (gardening).

Is there a way to store SQL db file in encrypted format or is there a way to upload only one table from that database? Actually I have 2 tables in db, one with data and second just with user data, which is related to table 1, but contains only ID's from first table, not data.

So I see as a better idea to backup only 2nd table with ID's and not whole db.

Comment: "However I don't want anyone to stole the data from db" -- then do not put it in a database on the user's phone. "is there a way to upload only one table from that database?" -- export the data to some other file, such as CSV or JSON, and back up that file. Or, have two separate databases, one for end-user data (that gets backed up) and one for your own data (that does not get backed up).

Comment: good idea with JSON, thanks! About stoling the data - common user can't access the app's db on device. More skilled maybe can with rooting the device, but not every user will do. The data are coming from my server, but to avoid traffic and improve performance, it is connected once and stores data in app's db. So by hacking the app or downloading as apk, users see no database as it is created only after installing. It is not top secret data, I just don't want someone to take it and use it in his app for example.